# Create persistent redux state backed by MongoDB in Electron + React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, electron, react-redux

I have an application based on [react-electron-boilerplate](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate), using the very same set of patterns. My application uses `mongodb` for a persistence layer, connecting to a remote database to maintain its state.

To get the current state, I usually do something like as follows in one of my action controllers (`app/actions/<whatever>.js`)

```
export function stepForward(step, action) {
  if (_.isUndefined(step)) {
    step = db.collection('steps').findOne({ current: true }).index; // just an example
  }
  return {
    type: STEP_FORWARD
  };
}
```

However, this does not necessarily write to the database. What I want is to maintain a *persistent* state, which is to say, write this state to a database whenever it changes (yes, I know this might be costly for large applications).

Is this possible to achieve with redux and mongodb?

Answer (score 3):

Although I started with the `finalReducer` pattern mentioned by Ian, it turned out to be much easier to use a Redux middleware:

```
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'

const persist = store => next => action => {
  next(action)
  persistData(store.getState())
}

const store = createStore(<reducer>, undefined, applyMiddleware(persist))
```

Answer (score 2):

Most definitely achievable. I would combine all of your reducers into a final reducer before creating your store. This final reducer would act on *any* action and persist the state to Mongo. Some pseudo-code as an example:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import <all of your other reducers>

const reducers = combineReducers({
    <other reducers here>
});

const finalReducer = (state, action) => {
    const nextState = reducers(state, action);

    //use whatever module you use to write to mongo...
    persistToMongo(nextState);

    return nextState;
};

const store = createStore(finalReducer, undefined);
```

Hopefully that's enough to get your creative juices flowing. Let me know if you need more help or clarity, and otherwise, good luck!

Comment: I know this is old, but for any passers-by, this goes against one of the 3 principals of redux: Changes are made with pure functions. Pure functions don't have any side effects (like modifying state, saving to a database, saving a dog from a burning building, etc...). Reducers should be pure functions. <-- Reason for my downvote.

Comment: Looking back on this (more than a year later) I agree with Jack. I would definitely use a middleware like daviestar suggests.